# How can I fix my trigger to allow it to compile?

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I have two tables :

1. `Boats (BUILDERNAME, MODEL, LENGTH_BY_FEET, BASE_PRICE)`
2. `Pricechanges (MODEL, CHANGEDATE, OLDPRICE, NEWPRICE)`.

I need to create a trigger that when the `Base_Price` of table `Boats` is updated it adds a row to `Pricechanges` table.

Here is what I have

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER PRICECHANGE  
  AFTER UPDATE OF BASE_PRICE ON BOATS   
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF UPDATING THEN
    INSERT INTO pricechanges (MODEL, CHANGEDATE, OLDPRICE, NEWPRICE)
    VALUES (model, SYSDATE, :old.base_price, :new.base_price)
END PRICECHANGE;
```

Having some trouble with. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a semicolon and an `END IF`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER PRICECHANGE  
  AFTER UPDATE OF BASE_PRICE ON BOATS   
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF UPDATING THEN
     INSERT INTO pricechanges (MODEL, CHANGEDATE, OLDPRICE, NEWPRICE)
     VALUES (model, SYSDATE, :old.base_price, :new.base_price);
   END IF;
END PRICECHANGE;
```

Also, because this is an `AFTER UPDATE` trigger the test for `IF UPDATING` is unnecessary, but it won't hurt anything.

Best of luck.